# How to know if edittext is scrolled to bottom?

Tags: android, android-edittext

In Android, how can I know if my edittext field is scrolled to the bottom, i.e. the last line is fully visible?

I tried this, but it seems to be too much code for a simple thing:

```
EditText et;
int scrollY   = et.getScrollY();
int sum = et.getHeight() + scrollY;
Layout layout = et.getLayout();
int lastVisibleLineNumber  = layout.getLineForVertical(sum);
int lineBottom = layout.getLineBottom(lastVisibleLineNumber);
int diff = lineBottom + layout.getBottomPadding() + et.getPaddingBottom() + et.getPaddingTop() - sum;

if (diff <= 0) // Scrolled to the bottom
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use

```
android:ellipsize="end"
```

to get bottom of edit text.

Answer (score 0):

You can try

```
int diff = et.getBottom() - (et.getHeight() + et.getScrollY());
```

Comment: I tried, but it doesn't work since it gets the bottom position in parents view, so even if the edittext is scrolled to the bottom, diff is something like 2000 (it's inside a scroll view).